# Typesetting and alignment of optimization problem where objective value row is excluded

Tags: amsmath, alignment, mathtools

I want to format my optimization problem like this (see picture for results):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{-1}
&\mathrlap{\minimize_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T g_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T h_t(x) + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n F_{ijk}(x) } \\
&\text{subject to} & \quad && \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i &\leq b_j, \quad && j = 1, \dots, m \\
&                  & \quad && \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} x_i &\leq d_j, \quad && j = 1, \dots, m
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the first row clashes with the equation numbering. One solution is to add `\hspace{...}` to one of the constraint rows to make sure that there is enough space for the numbering, but is there a cleaner way that does not need manual tuning?

[image: equation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to add several `\span` commands like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{-1}
&\minimize_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T g_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T h_t(x) + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n F_{ijk}(x)  \span \span \span \span \span \span \span \span \\
&\text{subject to} & \quad && \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i &\leq b_j, \quad && j = 1, \dots, m \hspace{0cm} \\
&                  & \quad && \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i       &\leq d_j, \quad && j = 1, \dots, m
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Answer (score 5):

You could break the minimize objective with `aligned`, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{-1}
&\mathrlap{\begin{aligned}
  \minimize_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} 
  \quad \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T g_t(x) + 
  \sum_{t=1}^T h_t(x)\\
  + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n F_{ijk}(x) 
\end{aligned}} \\
&\text{subject to} & \quad && \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} 
  x_i &\leq b_j, \quad && j = 1, \dots, m \\
&                  & \quad && \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} 
  x_i &\leq d_j, \quad && j = 1, \dots, m
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ALTERNATIVE**

Here's an alternative that keeps the first line unsplit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&{\minimize_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}} && \quad
  \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T g_t(x) + 
  \sum_{t=1}^T h_t(x)+ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n F_{ijk}(x) 
\\
&\text{subject to} && \quad \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} 
  x_i \leq b_j, \quad  j = 1, \dots, m \\
&                  && \quad \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} 
  x_i \leq d_j, \quad j = 1, \dots, m
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution, but what if I want to actually utilize all of the horizontal space available?

Comment: @latex_is_hard If it doesn't fit on a single line, I'm not sure how significant the choice is, where to break.  However, the double-backslash in the `aligned` environment denotes the break point, so you could change its location.

Comment: Hmm, it should fit in a single line. If I put `\hspace{2cm}` after the first constraint it fits in one line and looks good. But I am looking for a solution that does the spacing automatically.

Comment: @latex_is_hard For multi-line equations that are display-style, there is no "automatic" approach.  Automatic spacing can only occur for inline-style math that occurs in the context of a text paragraph.

Comment: Ok, maybe automatic is not the right word. My point is that I want to avoid adding hard-coded values for lengths. I think I might have a solution using the `\span` command. See my other answer.

Comment: @latex_is_hard Please see my alternative approach

Comment: This is the output I want for this specific case, but for example, removing the a_ij will make the constraints unaligned with respect to the \leq.

Comment: @latex_is_hard That is where phantoms help, as in `\sum_{i=1}^n \phantom{c_{ij}} x_i \leq b_j` for the line where `a_{ij}` is removed.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a cleaner way that does not need manual tuning?

I don't think that the constraints need to be aligned visually with an element in the objective-function row. Hence, I'd place the constraints in an `alignat{3}` environment and embed this environment in a `gather` environment. I'd even be tempted to add some extra vertical whitespace -- via `\\[2\jot]` -- right after the objective-function row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\minimize_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \quad 
\sum_{t=1}^T f_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T g_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T h_t(x) 
  + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n F_{ijk}(x) \\[2\jot]
\begin{alignat}{3}
\text{subject to} \quad 
 &\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x_i &&\leq b_j, &\quad& j=1,\dots,m \\
 &\sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij}x_i &&\leq d_j, && j=1,\dots,m
\end{alignat}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also good, but what if I want to align the constraints by the \leq?

Comment: @latex_is_hard - Please see the amended answer,

Comment: Ok, this is great. But I really do want the "minimize" and the "subject to" to be at least roughly aligned.

Comment: @latex_is_hard - Are you certain that your readers will necessarily understand better what you're trying to say if "minimize" and "subject to" are placed in close visual proximity?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it looks nicer to me.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider `optidef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% use consecutive numbers rather than subequations
\xpatchcmd{\env@BaseMiniExclam@process}{\begin{subequations}}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\env@BaseMiniExclam@process}{\end{subequations}}{}{}{}
% the subscript to minimize should not be in display style
\xpatchcmd{\bodyobjLong}{\displaystyle}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\bodyobjLong}{\displaystyle}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}
{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{
  \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T g_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T h_t(x)}{}{}
\breakObjective{\qquad + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n F_{ijk}(x)}
\addConstraint{\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i}{\leq b_j,}{j = 1, \dots, m}
\addConstraint{\sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} x_i}{\leq d_j,}{j = 1, \dots, m}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

I made a couple of fixes: by default, the `mini!` environment would number the lines as (1a), (1b), (1c) and (1d). If you prefer this format, comment out the first two `\xpatchcmd` lines.

The second fix is for the subscript to “minimize”: I find it wrong that it's in display style and not like a standard subscript.

[image]

You can also define your own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% define mini!! for consecutive numbering (not subequations)
\NewEnviron{BaseMiniExclamExclam}[7]{%
  \selectConstraintMult{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\localOptimalVariable}{#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{b}}{\begingroup\allowdisplaybreaks}{}%
  #4
  \begin{alignat}{5}
    \bodyobj{#2}{#3}{#6}{#5}
    \BODY
  \end{alignat}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{b}}{\endgroup}{}%
  \setStandardMini
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mini!!}{
  D||{\defaultProblemFormat} O{\defaultConstraintFormat} D<>{} m m m m
}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}%
  % Short version problem
  {\setFormatShort{min}{#2}\BaseMiniExclamExclam{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{min}{#3}}%
  % Long version problem
  {\setFormatLong{minimise}{#2}\BaseMiniExclamExclam{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{minimise}{#3}}%
}{\endBaseMiniExclam\toggletrue{bodyCon}}



\makeatletter
% the subscript to minimize should not be in display style
\xpatchcmd{\bodyobjLong}{\displaystyle}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\bodyobjLong}{\displaystyle}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!!}
{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{
  \sum_{t=1}^T f_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T g_t(x) + \sum_{t=1}^T h_t(x)}{}{}
\breakObjective{\qquad + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n F_{ijk}(x)}
\addConstraint{\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i}{\leq b_j,}{j = 1, \dots, m}
\addConstraint{\sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} x_i}{\leq d_j,}{j = 1, \dots, m}
\end{mini!!}

\end{document}
```

Note that I used “minimise”. It's a bit unfortunate that the package author hardwired the keywords, instead of making them customizable.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have considered this. I feel that this package lacks some flexibility though. For example, what if I want minimise instead of minimize?

Comment: @latex_is_hard See edit

Comment: This looks good, but it feels a bit overkill to start defining new environments and the like, but if there is no simpler solution, that is okay. Also, when I use this package in a beamer presentation, the font differs from the rest of the presentation for some reason.

Comment: @latex_is_hard You could lobby the package author…

Comment: You have written "minimise" instead of "minimize" +1